# Android daily function execute and upload to server

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to create daily routine for my puzzle game: I want to execute function that creates "The Grid" of my game every 24 hour on the same time each day and upload the result of that function to any server I can read from with my app.
I'm using `Firebase` with my app so I prefer a solution with `firebase`. What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You probably will need to create a Firebase function triggered by an HTTP request, and create a cron job that will do this HTTP request daily. Then, inside your function you do all the changes that you need (including uploading the results).

Take a look in this [article](https://medium.com/@ales.musto/firebase-cloud-functions-that-run-on-a-set-schedule-b5d62cbbc476).

Answer (score 1):

Although you could use Android's [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) to perform time-based operations on the device itself, as per the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#tradeoffs): "It may not be the best choice for your app, particularly if you need to trigger network operations."

Since you prefer a solution with Firebase, a much more robust approach is to use Cloud Functions for Firebase to send messages to your app via Firebase Cloud Messaging:

1. For the first step, I'd suggest you to follow [this official tutorial](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html) on how to schedule (cron) jobs with Cloud Functions for Firebase. It uses Cloud Pub/Sub but you could just as well use [HTTP-triggered](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) functions
2. Now, the function, once triggered, may create a new grid, store it in db and send messages to your (Android/iOS/Web) apps via [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) to inform them that a new grid is available for download.